# Why would the white wire in a fixture be wired to the exposed ground?

Tags: wiring

I am replacing light fixtures around the house and came across a weird wiring situation I have never encountered before. The house was built before 1930 but was stripped down and rebuilt before we bought it from a flipper last year. Most things were redone including plumbing and electrical etc.

The original fixture had the black wire from fixture tied to two white wires with black tape (so two black wires I beleive) but the white wire from fixture was tied to the exposed copper ground in the ceiling box. The remaining two black wires coming from the ceiling from each of the two whips in the ceiling box were both tied together and not to the fixture at all. The fixture is wired to a single switch and is wired together with another fixture in the closet a couple feet away, I assume that's why there are two whips coming out of the ceiling box.

I wired the new fixture the same as the one I removed and it works fine. I'm just paranoid it's going to burst into flames some day is a spider spits on it or something. Thanks in advance for your expertise!

Comment: Is the other fixture wired to the same switch? Have you checked how that one is wired?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please, as well as the inside of the switch box?

Comment: Do you know if you have cables or conduit(with wires inside) in the house?  Does seem like someone might have cut corners doing the electrics.

Answer (score 7):

This work was done illegally.  Somebody wished they had used /3 cable (like post 2011 Code requires).  So instead, they used the white wire as their "second hot" and bootlegged neutral off the safety ground wire.

That's probably because they extended off this circuit (either beyond the switch or beyond the lamp) and needed to carry always-hot *and* neutral (as well as switched-hot between lamp and switch).  2021 was a "goldrush" time in real estate, and that means all the competent electricians get to pick and choose the most profitable jobs/employers.  A bunch of "bottom of the barrel" tradesmen who are unemployable in a normal economy thus end up doing the less desirable jobs.

Now it's up to you to figure out if this was legacy work done decades ago, or by this flipper last year. If the flipper might have done it, I'd be on them like white on rice. Somebody needs to pay for *competent, licensed* tradesmen searching the house for similar shortcuts, and it shouldn't be you.  Disgraceful, the person needs to be punished.

I would certainly make the city inspector know, as they are the only person who can "connect the dots" if that person is going around doing many homes this way.